# Como posso saber o título de um video do YouTube durante o download?

Tags: python, youtube-api

Estou fazendo um programa que baixa os videos no YouTube de um canal. Mas não quero fazer download de todos os videos, mas somente daqueles que tem uma palavra especifica. Como posso fazer isso?

```
import youtube_dl
import os

ydl_opts = {}
os.chdir(os.getcwd())
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                           
      ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVJqulBlIchaIsGFK-hCKFQ'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução é usar `ydl.extract_info`:

```py
import youtube_dl

ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL()
result = ydl.extract_info('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVJqulBlIchaIsGFK-hCKFQ', download=False)

for i in range(len(result['entries'][0]['entries'])):
      print(result['entries'][0]['entries'][i]['title'])
```

Retorna:

```
Eletrônicos São Divertidos
Galinhas verdes soltam laser
Magicas1
Minecraft parte 2
Artes #1
bonéco de neve aspen
snow mess aspen
can s top filling
Dudu versus Treinador no Clash Royale!
Dudu Contra Barça no Fifa 15!
Dudu Detona no Fifa 15 (Parte 2)
Dudu Detona no Fifa 15 (Parte 1)
```

Para usar adequadamente esse método é importante entender a estrutura do objeto `result`. Ele é um dicionário em que as chaves são os dados do objeto linkado (vídeo, playlist, canal). No presente caso, as chaves de `result` são:

```
dict_keys(['_type', 'entries', 'id', 'title', 'description', 'extractor', 'webpage_url', 'webpage_url_basename', 'extractor_key'])
```

Note que `entries` é uma chave que contém a lista de vídeos do canal. Para cada vídeo dentro do canal existe outro dicionário com as informações do vídeo. Veja um exemplo usando o primeiro vídeo:

```
print(result['entries'][0].keys())
```

Retorna:

```
dict_keys(['_type', 'entries', 'id', 'title', 'description', 'extractor', 'webpage_url', 'webpage_url_basename', 'extractor_key'])
```

Agora fica fácil fazer o download condicional ao nome. Basta adcicionar:

```py
for i in range(len(result['entries'][0]['entries'])):
      if 'Eletrônicos' in result['entries'][0]['entries'][i]['title']:
            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                  ydl.download([result['entries'][0]['entries'][i]['webpage_url']])
      else:
            print("I will not download {}".format(result['entries'][0]['entries'][i]['title']))
```

Comment: Obrigado Lucas funcionou

Comment: Imagina. Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida.